# Python Beautiful Soup cannot find table

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a web scraping code that cannot find a table. 
My code looks like:

```
site = 'http://etfdb.com/compare/market-cap/'
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(site, headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
table = soup.find('table', {"class":"table mm-mobile-table table-striped 
table-bordered"})
```

The tables HTML looks like:

```
<table class="table mm-mobile-table table-striped table-bordered" data-
icons-prefix="fa" data-icons="{&quot;columns&quot;:&quot;fa-th&quot;}" data-
striped="true" data-toggle="table">
```

but for some reason my code always returns table as none. I do not know why but any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There are no tables in the `soup` (nor in the `page`). Probably the server does not recognize 'Mozilla/5.0' as a valid agent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that there is incorrect markup making large sections of the code commented out i.e

```
<!-->.
```

the fix was to replace these elements then parse the HTML.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
site = 'http://etfdb.com/compare/market-cap/'
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(site, headers=hdr)
res = urlopen(req)
rawpage = res.read()
page = rawpage.replace("<!-->", "")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table", {"class":"table mm-mobile-table table-striped table-bordered"})
print (table)
```

Tested on Python 2.7.12

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
site = 'http://etfdb.com/compare/market-cap/'
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(site, headers=hdr)
res = urlopen(req)
rawpage = res.read().decode("utf-8") 
page = rawpage.replace('<!-->', '')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table", {"class":"table mm-mobile-table table-striped table-bordered"})
print (table)
```

Tested on Python 3.5.2

Gives:

```
 <table class="table mm-mobile-table table-striped table-bordered" data-icons='{"columns":"fa-th"}' data-icons-prefix="fa" data-striped="true" data-toggle="table"><thead><tr><th class="show-td" data-field="symbol">Symbol</th> <th class="show-td" data-field="name">Name</th> <th class="show-td" data-field="aum">AUM</th> <th class="show-td" data-field="avg-volume">Avg Volume</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="show-td" data-th="Symbol"><a href="/etf/SPY/">SPY</a></td> <td class="show-td" data-th="Name"><a href="/etf/SPY/">SPDR S&amp;P 500 ETF</a></td> <td class="show-td" data-th="AUM">$236,737,519.17</td> <td class="show-td" data-th="Avg Volume">73,039,883</td></tr> <tr><td class="show-td" data-th="Symbol"><a href="/etf/IVV/">IVV</a></td> <td class="show-td" data-th="Name"><a href="/etf/IVV/">iShares Core S&amp;P 500 ETF</a></td> <td class="show-td" data-th="AUM">$115,791,603.10</td> <td class="show-td" data-th="Avg Volume">3,502,931</td></tr> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what exactly you want to parse

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

Then you can very well verify if it parsed properly

```
print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know maybe it's because their code is not well-structured [deliberately] and BeautifulSoup couldn't parse it. But maybe this helps you:

```
import re    # to extract table with regex
table_soup = BeautifulSoup( re.findall(r'<table.*>.*</table>', page.read())[0] )
```

Also you can investigate further with something like this:

```
for tag in soup.find_all():
   if tag.name == 'div':
      if str(tag).find("table-striped") > -1:
         print repr( str(tag)[:100] )
```

To see which `div` tags contain the `table`, if any:

```
'<div class="mm-header">\n<div class="container">\n<div class="row">\n<div class="col-xs-12">\n<div class'
'<div class="container">\n<div class="row">\n<div class="col-xs-12">\n<div class="mm-user-links hidden-x'
'<div class="row mm-header-content">\n<div class="col-sm-4 mm-header-logos">\n<button class="navbar-tog'
'<div class="col-sm-4 mm-header-logos">\n<button class="navbar-toggle">\n<span class="fa fa-bars"></spa'
```

So I guess BeautifulSoup couldn't break down the last one into child tags.

**Edit:**

1. Sorry I forgot to add `page.read()` to get page source first, see the second line again.
2. If you don't want to use regex, **you can use a better parser** rather than the default one: `html5lib`

First install it:

`# pip install html5lib`

The you can use it by:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')`